# Safety of adding dried hot pepper to opened jar of pickles

Tags: food-safety, canning, spoilage

I have a particular brand of jarred pickles I buy from a local supplier. They're some kind of beer pickle, and the brine has a vinegar and IPA type of taste, and it's loaded with garlic and dill. Very tasty indeed.

I also have a fondness for hot peppers. I recently bought some dried powdered hot peppers, including [smoked ghost pepper (which tastes awesome)](http://www.pickyourpepper.com/spices/smoked-chipotle-spices/black-skull-ghost-pepper-chili-powder) and [dried Trinidad Mogura Scorpion pepper](http://www.pickyourpepper.com/spices/Hot-Chili-Pepper-Powder/Red-Tail-Trinidad-Moruga-Scorpion-Chili-Powder), which is mostly heat, and not too much flavor.

Would it be safe to add a teaspoon of each of these powders to a 700mL jar of pickles (yes, I love them obscenely hot) and store the result in the fridge for up to a couple weeks? My primary concern is the hot peppers causing spoilage by adding them.

Thank you.

Comment: I do the same thing I have never had a problem.  I thought this was the idea behind pickling.  Good question!  I don't see where in this process bacteria can be introduced.

Comment: @Chef_Code The hot pepper would be added after opening the sealed jars, rather than before processing/heating the jars.

Comment: IMO, adding the pepper at that point will not add heat to the pickles, especially if it is left to rest in the fridge.

Comment: @Max I've had good luck so far. It's mostly on the surface, but the smoked ghost pepper adds an amazing element to the taste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shouldn't be a safety concern.  Bacteria could certainly be introduced (if you use your hands to add the pepper or a cross-contaminated utensil), however, the acidic environment of the pickling liquid should keep any possible bacterial growth in check.  The other contaminant to consider would be botulism, but again, in a pickling environment (high acidity, high salt) this is not a concern.  So...make your pickles as spicy as you like.

Comment: And we are talking about adding some spices which is a way to improve the time your food can last. See [here](http://www.news.cornell.edu/stories/1998/03/food-bacteria-spice-survey-shows-why-some-cultures-it-hot) for a study on that matter. Hot pepper appears 12th on the list of spices with antimicrobial properties.